# Arduino: how to read a csv file in Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to build a simple turret that follows my face. For the face tracking feature, I am using Python `OpenCV` to track my face and storing the X and Y coordinates in a `CSV` file. How would I read that `CSV` file in Arduino?

Another question: Is my approach to this problem a good idea, or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Reading a CSV on an Arduino certainly doesn't involve OpenCV, AI or machine learning. Don't abuse tags, just because you can fit 5 in there doesn't imply you must.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend skipping the detour over the filesystem.

I guess in this case UART would probably be good if you want 2 devices to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

In general your idea to transfer this data serialized as .csv is OK. It is redundant to use file for that though. Instead you should output csv serialized coordinates directly to serial port that arduino would listen to.

I'm not much into Python but here's an article that could be helpful: https://friendlyuser.github.io/posts/tech/2023/Using_PySerial_in_Python_A_Comprehensive_Guide/

When it comes to using serial communication in Arduino here's another one:
https://www.programmingelectronics.com/serial-read/